# Why is Casandra's bomb no longer a threat?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the episode *1969* when SG-1 was a bit too early going though the Stargate during the Solar Flare and was flung into the future, waiting for them was an old woman who Sam confirmed to be Casandra.

From what I remember Casandra's bomb would form and detonate while she was within the vicinity of the Stargate and it was only "disarmed" by moving her far enough away from it.

So is Casandra's bomb no longer a threat, particularly in SG-1's original time? If so how was the bomb disarmed to the point where it is no longer a threat?

Comment: Left intentionally vague;  CARTER
Already? But there's so much that you…

CASSANDRA
You of all people know I can't.

Comment: @Richard that line I thought Sam was about to ask about their future which was Casandra's past and Casandra was referring to how Sam knows the dangers of altering the future which may lead to a scenario where it's not possible for Casandra to wait for them

Comment: Cassie had been back on base as a teenager (in season 5 iirc), so if anything were to happen, it would have happened then (from her own temporal perspective of course), which would have been really bad for SG-1, since the SGC -- and more importantly the gate -- would have been gone and they would have been stuck in the future....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was line where Carter says something about the bomb going away:

> Carter: "I didnt feel completely at ease until I knew the object was shrinking and being reabsorbed into her system"

["Singularity"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/1.15_%22Singularity%22_Transcript)

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the quote and a link to the transcript; your memory was correct

Comment: I thought the bomb initially was absorbed into Casandra's body so when Sam said it was being re-absorbed has Ewa referring it the bomb returning to the state it was in before Casandra went though the gate